# Spin off BuddyPress into its own SE?

Tags: discussion

BuddyPress is considered off-topic for WPSE. However, it is a big ecosystem in its own right and has a lot of third party development going on. Perhaps WPSE would be somewhat less overwhelmed if BuddyPress questions could be migrated to another stack (one just for BuddyPress development).

If enough of us think this is a good idea, I will propose the new stack.

Who is willing to yes to this in principle?

Edit: If this is to be done, I mean to see it done well. This meta is not the only place I have posted the proposal. I've also posted on a WordPress dev blog I write for and (more importantly) [in the BuddyPress forums](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/who-would-be-with-me-for-proposing-a-buddypress-stack-exchange/#post-316190).

Comment: This would be great, I don't know much about BP though, but from my efforts to get the WC stack running I'll say it's a lot harder than it looks, you can get people to show interest and get through the first step but then people have to ask and answer questions and at a high enough rate for it to graduate on, which is easier said than done, as well as think of good questions that aren't just fixing individual peoples problems. If the stack is full of questions about how to fix my loop, but nobody asks how to write loops, it'll never get off the ground.

Comment: With WC, lots of positive sentiment, but nobody wanted to answer questions, and it didn't meet the activity requirements within the time limits. BP is in danger of the same thing happening if you're not careful

Comment: If I understand, what you are saying is that this is not going to be easy and that there needs to be a critical mass of experts to get things off the ground? I would agree with that sentiment, which is why I have been reaching out to the community to gauge the level of support and the number of experts available.

Comment: You're also going to need a well defined scope with reasons behind it. There is the danger that you just become a free support hub for a premium BuddyPress add-on that newcomers can't even see unless they spend the money, or that all the time is spent  on open ended questions and helping people fix issues with unrelated JS/CSS  libraries because the site they used them on was built with BuddyPress. Try to get others to also do what you're doing as well as pledge support

Comment: Yes, BuddyPress SE could suffer from the same problems reported for WordPress SE. At least the community for BPSE would go into things forearmed with the experience of WPSE. Hopefully avoiding some of the things WPSE encountered and including some of things WPSE did not include but maybe could have.  If WPSE wants to make BuddyPress on topic, that's a whole other debate.

Answer (score 3):

This has been brought up a few times but with WooCommerce as the stack. The problem I've continued to see is that there's not enough dedicated interested to create its own stack. Someone would have to take the helm so to speak and garner interest from multiple communities to get them involved in an [Area 51 Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) for the BuddyPress site. A good place to start is [their FAQs page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: This is not the only place I have posted this. I've also posted on a WordPress dev blog and the BuddyPress forums. If this is to be done, I intend to see it done well.

Comment: That is good news! I just wanted to point out that the process can only truly move forward with a proper Area 51 Proposal as linked above.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt did you start a proposal for buddypress?

Comment: @TomJNowell Not yet. I did not see any point in starting without first finding out if there was broad enough support for such a SE.